# Inside which type of parenthesis should we use $ to expand a variable in bash

Tags: bash

Inside which type of parenthesis `(), (()), {}, [[ ]], $( ), $(( ))` should we use the dollar sign before the variable to expand it?

Comment: Looks like an exam question

Comment: What have you tried? What research did you do? Isn't  it easy to spawn a shell and test all combinations?

Comment: Yes, of course I can try it myself. But I wanted to know if there was a logical reason behind it, or a rule.

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to say is if there's sort of a pattern of when to use them or not.

Comment: The source of all rules is the POSIX shell command language specification. https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html

Comment: For those who marked this as duplicate... this question is not asking what do those parenthesis do, it's asking about how to deal with a variable inside those parenthesis...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arithmetic expansion is the one that doesn't need dollar sings, which means both `((...))` and `$((...))`. But you don't need the dollar sign in other arithmetic contexts, either, e.g. in array indices.

```sh
arr=(a b c)
x=1
echo "${arr[x]}"  # b
```

See "Arithmetic Evaluation" in `man bash`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Quotes added.

Answer (score 1):

It depends...
Try it yourself in a bash.
A big Country is in array number 4

```
$ array=(0 1 2 3 COUNTRY 5 6 7 8 9)
$ echo ${array[4]}
COUNTRY
```

And now lets expand it...

```
$ array=(0 1 2 3 $COUNTRY 5 6 7 8 9)
$ echo ${array[4]}
DE
```

...to a very little country.

But what should it be?
My personnel like...

```
$ array=(0 1 2 3 ${COUNTRY} 5 6 7 8 9)
$ echo ${array[4]}
DE
```

...better because it makes it clearer that `${COUNTRY}` is a Variable than a single Dollarsign (`$`).